# Even after password encrypted with hash Salt on client side at javascript still it passes to browses memory in plain text password code in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, encryption, plaintext

I have encrypted the password at client side used javascript to do password encrypted with hash salt aes encryption.

But when we passed the encrypted password to server side code asp.net with vb.

it get stored in browsers memory as in plain text.

How to avoid to store password in browsers memory browser dump file as in plain text.

We have resolved application security issue

**password can steal from browser memory**

Comment: "it get stored in browsers memory as in plain text." <- are you decrypting it into a string variable somewhere?

Comment: Yes sir at server side but it was in hidden field and i have used salt hash tech.    Please help sir andrew mortimer

Comment: Yes sir but while sending from client side to server side i have copy encrypted password in hidden field and clear actual password field. And at server side i have used hidden field to decrypt the password. AES decryption. Aes decryption with hash salt used. As soon as password get validate i have cleared all fields related to password at server side on same page

Comment: "How to avoid to store password in browsers memory." You can't. The password is entered in plaintext, obviously, so it must be in the browser's memory at some point. You have to rely on the OS to protect it. If you're worried about compromised memory, client side encryption does absolutely nothing to begin with because the encryption key is in memory too. You can use a password-less authentication scheme, or multi-factor authentication.